# tipo MIME de los programas escritos en lenguaje C (.c o c++) en PHP

Tags: php, mime

Tengo la duda de cual el es MIME en PHP de los programas escritos en lenguaje C ya sea .c o c++ lo que pasa es que en mi aplicación necesito que solo puedan subir archivos con esa extensión, quiero hacer un filtro algo asi:

`if( $_FILES['archivo']['type']=='image/png')` pero para extension .c o c++

Comment: Hola yept. *"algo asi"*? Si lo has probado, qué error o problemas te han surgido. Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta y añadir informacion relevante. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

> Para C

```
if($_FILES['archivo']['type']=='text/x-c')
```

> Para C++

```
if($_FILES['archivo']['type']=='text/plain')
```

Además, tenemos maneras para saber el `MIME` de un fichero:

```
$mime = new finfo;

$filemime = $mime->file($tufichero, FILEINFO_MIME);
```

Saludos,